# IDS/IPS size of payload analysis

Tags: snort

I’ve been searching for a while in order to find out the typical/minimum size of payload analysis while configuring security devices such as IDS/IPS.

I know it is possible to configure within SNORT rules both Offset and Depth parameters. Sort speech: a SNORT rule configured with a 1 byte Offset and 7 bytes depth will analyze incoming packets from 1-7 bytes of payload + Header size.

I know depth parameter value varies from 1-65535 but i’d like to know what is the minimum size of bytes for an accurate traffic analysis.

As an example, if I receive a meterpreter payload which is roughly 700 bytes size, do I need to scan the whole packet in order to raise an alert?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node33.html#SECTION00467000000000000000

Comment: thanks for the info. I read the manual before posting but nothing clear so far. As well as it is possible to configure manual alerts with fields such as Offset, Depth and so on, what I want to know is typical payload sizes that IDS work with.